# Replace substring with string from second csv file

Tags: perl

Earlier I was working on a loop within a loop and if a match was made it would replace the entire string from the second loop file. Now i have a slightly different situation. I'm trying to replace a substring from the first loop with a string from the second loop. They're both csv files and semicolon delimited. What i'm trying to replace are special characters: from the numerical code to the character itself The first file looks like:

```
1;2;bla&#322blabla &#261bla;7;8
3;4;bl&#261blabla;9;10
2;3;blablabla&#261a&#322;8;9
```

and the second file has the numerical code and the corresponding character:

```
&#260;;Ą
&#261;;ą
&#478;;Ǟ
&#193;;Á
&#225;;á
&#194;;Â
&#322;;ł
```

The first semicolon in the second file belongs to the numerical code of the corresponding character and should not be used to split the file. The result should be:

```
1;2;blałblabla ąbla;7;8
3;4;bląblabla;9;10
2;3;blablablaąał;8;9
```

This is the code I have. How can i fix this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inputfile1 = shift || die "input/output!\n";
my $inputfile2 = shift || die "input/output!\n";
my $outputfile = shift || die "output!\n";

open my $INFILE1,  '<', $inputfile1 or die "Used/Not found :$!\n";
open my $INFILE2,  '<', $inputfile2 or die "Used/Not found :$!\n";
open my $OUTFILE, '>', $outputfile or die "Used/Not found :$!\n";

my $infile2_pos = tell $INFILE2;

while (<$INFILE1>) {
s/"//g;
my @elements = split /;/, $_;
seek $INFILE2, $infile2_pos, 0;

    while (<$INFILE2>) {
    s/"//g;
    my @loopelements = split /;/, $_;

    #### The problem part ####
    if (($elements[2] =~ /\&\#\d{3}\;/g) and (($elements[2]) eq ($loopelements[0]))){
        $elements[2] =~ s/(\&\#\d{3}\;)/$loopelements[1]/g;
        print "$2. elements[2]\n";
                }
    #### End problem part #####
    }

my $output_line = join(";", @elements);
print $OUTFILE $output_line;
#print "\n"
}

close $INFILE1;
close $INFILE2;
close $OUTFILE;

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your character codes are standard Unicode entities, you are better off using [`HTML::Entities`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aEntities) to decode them.

This program processes the data you show in your *first file* and ignores the *second file* completely. The output seems to be what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Entities 'decode_entities';

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

while (<DATA>) {
  print decode_entities($_);
}

__DATA__
1;2;bla&#322blabla &#261bla;7;8
3;4;bl&#261blabla;9;10
2;3;blablabla&#261a&#322;8;9
```

**output**

```
1;2;blałblabla ąbla;7;8
3;4;bląblabla;9;10
2;3;blablablaąał8;9
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much easier:)

Comment: @Borodin so after setting binmode to utf8, does this only work if you print?  would it work if I stored the return of decode_entities to a var?

Answer (score 0):

You split your `@elements` at every occurrence of `;`, which is then removed. You will not find it in your data, the semicolon in your Regexp can never match, so no substitutions are done.

Anyway, using `seek` is somewhat disturbing for me. As you have a reasonable number of replacement codes (<5000), you might consider putting them into a hash:

```
my %subst;
while(<$INFILE2>){
    /^&#(\d{3});;(.*)\n/;
    $subst{$1} = $2;
}
```

Then we can do:

```
while(<$INFILE1>){
   s| &# (\d{3}) | $subst{$1} // "&#$1" |egx;
       # (don't try to concat undef
       # when no substitution for our code is defined)
   print $OUTFILE $_;
}
```

We do not have to split the files or view them as CSV data if replacement should occur everywhere in INFILE1. My solution should speed things up a bit (parsing INFILE2 only once). Here I assumed your input data is correct and the number codes are not terminated by a semicolon but by length. You might want to remove that from your Regexes.(i.e. `m/&#\d{3}/`)

If you have trouble with character encodings, you might want to open your files with :uft8 and/or `use Encode` or similar.

Comment: Haha so stupid of me! I guess it's friday:p Would have never thought of that approach! Trying it right now:) So just to be sure: leave the whole seek/tell part out of the code?